# How to copy/reference an object and updating values in a Linked List

Tags: java, c#, object, oop, reference

I'm trying to understand how **copy/reference** works in the algorithm below to solve LeetCode's '*Merge Two Sorted Lists*' problem.

This algorithm uses the **iteration** approach to merge the **linked lists**, initially using a '*head*' node and initializing it with the value *0*. After that, the object from the *head* node is **copied** to another *handler* node. After that, the value of the handler node's next is changed at each iteration of the loop to *traverse the linked list*, but the *head* node remains with the current value as *0*, but the next nodes are *updated* and the *head.next* is returned to the end of iteration.

I did not understand how the *head* node had all the values of the *next* property updated and the current property 'val' did not, instead the *handler* had the property *val* and the *next* updated and at no time had it had a new assignment for *head*.

```
public static ListNode MergeTwoLists(ListNode list1, ListNode list2)
        {
            ListNode head = new ListNode(0);
            ListNode handler = head;

            while (list1 != null && list2 != null)
            {
                if (list1.val <= list2.val)
                {
                    handler.next = list1;
                    list1 = list1.next;
                }
                else
                {
                    handler.next = list2;
                    list2 = list2.next;
                }
                handler = handler.next;
            }

            if (list1 != null)
                handler.next = list1;
            else if (list2 != null)
                handler.next = list2;

            return head.next;
        }
```

```
    public class ListNode
    {
        public int val;
        public ListNode next;
        public ListNode(int val = 0, ListNode next = null)
        {
            this.val = val;
            this.next = next;
        }
    }
```

**LeetCode**: https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-two-sorted-lists/

**Solution** I'm referring to (it's in java but I'm testing in c#): https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-two-sorted-lists/discuss/9772/Java-solution-with-real-world-concerns-real-world-concerns

Comment: Read on "sentinel values"... The head is only used to make code uniform and only `head.next` used/returned.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Thanks for the answer, I didn't know these "sentinel values". 
Now I understand his goal, but I would like to confirm if I understand the update part between the two objects. 
It is only updating the value of the 'next' property of the sentinel node 'head' since the first assignment with '0' because the only assignment performed in the properties of the 'handler' is in the 'next' property and not in the 'val' property. Is that correct?